# Timing of YoutubeLive Dashboard video display

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm under development iOS RTMP Client library(https://github.com/shogo4405/lf.swift)
Dashboard(https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard) takes a time to appear video when start publishing.

The status is Online but the live video appears after seconds as below.

For

- 30FPS -> 5sec
- 15FPS -> 10sec

Is this YouTube specifications?

Is there any way to display shortly (3sec...) ?